# How to fix my radio buttons to be inline?

Tags: html, css

Basically I created a couple radio buttons, then hid the actual buttons, and made the labels the buttons. For some reason they won't display inline and I can't quite seem to figure out why. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```css
.ReviewBox {
 width:64%;
 height:600px;
 position:relative;
 left:18%;
 background-color:#4795d7;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 box-shadow:0px 2px 4px black;
 border-radius:4px;
}

.ReviewBox input {
 visibility:hidden; 
 width:0;
 display:inline;
}

.ReviewBox label:hover {
 color:#00aedb;
}

.ReviewBox input:checked + label {
 color:#0900ff;
}

.ReviewBox p {
 position:absolute;
 left:12%;
 color:white;
}

.ReviewBox label {
 position:relative;
 left:45%;
 color:white;
 display:inline;
}

.ReviewHeader {
 position:relative;
 left:7%;
 top:32px;
 font-size:26px;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 1px black;
 font-family:Lobster;
 color:white;
}

.Server {
 top:75px;
 font-size:15px;
}

.Names  label{
 top:27px;
 font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ReviewBox">
   
   <h2 class="ReviewHeader">Let Us Know How We Did</h2>
   
   <div>
    <p class="Server">Server</p>
    <div class="Names">
    
     <input type="radio" name="Names" value="Juan" id="Juan">
     <label for="Juan">Juan</label>
     
    </div>
    
    <div class="Names">
    
     <input type="radio" name="Names" value="Sebastian" id="Sebastian">
     <label for="Sebastian">Sebastian</label>
     
    </div>
   </div>
```

Heres a JSFiddle of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/u6u53916/1/

Comment: jfiddle links must be accompanied by code.  Please edit your post to comply with the rules.

Comment: You need to add `display: inline;` to your radio button wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="names">
    <input type="radio" name="Names" value="Juan" id="Juan"/>
    <label for="Juan">Juan</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Names" value="Pablo" id="Pablo"/>
    <label for="Pablo">Pablo</label>
</div>
```

Just remove the middle `<div class="names">` so that it is a single div enclosing the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

just add `display: inline;` to your `Names` class. it's your code + what you're looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/kywno6q0/